# A class attribute instantiated as a list is being seen as a string when called by a method in another class. Need help finding where I went wrong

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am learning OOP in Python and ran into this issue. When I select Modify note (option 3) from App class, and want to modify a tag, I get the following error: the "self.tags is an 'str' object and has no attribute 'extend'". This did not happen when I did not have the App class, and tested the modify_note method directly from the note and notebook classes.

```
import datetime, sys
last_id = 0
class Note:
    
    def __init__(self, memo, tags=[]):
        global last_id
        last_id = last_id + 1
        self.id = last_id
        self.created_on = datetime.date.today()
        self.memo = memo
        self.tags = tags

    def modify_memo(self, memo):
        self.memo = memo
        
    def add_tags(self,tags=[]):
        print("self_tags, tags-type",type(self.tags), type(tags))# wanted to see what the type this shows
        self.tags.extend(tags)

    def show_note(self):
        print("Id:",self.id, "Memo:", self.memo,"Tags:", self.tags)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

class Notebook:
    def __init__ (self, notes=[]):
        self.notes = notes  # it was []

    def add_note(self, memo,tags=[]):
        note = Note(memo,tags)  
        self.notes.append(note)
        print(type(note.tags))

    def scroll(self):
       for note in self.notes:
            note.show_note()
            print(type(note.tags))
    
    def modify_note(self,id,memo='',tags=[]):
        print("modifying",id,memo,tags)

        found = False
        #for note in nb.notes: # tested this. Discuss in class
        for note in self.notes:
            
            if note.get_id() == id:
                found = True
                if memo != '':
                    note.modify_memo(memo)
                if tags:
                    print("notebook modify_note",type(tags),tags, type(note.tags),note.tags)  
                    note.add_tags(tags)
        if not found:
            print("Invalid note id:", id)

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.notebook = Notebook()
        self.choices = {
            1: self.add_note,
            2: self.show_notes,
            3: self.modify_note,
            #4: self.search_note,
            5: self.quit
        }

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            selection = int(input("Input your Choice:"))
            action = self.choices[selection]
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("Invalid choice!")

    def display_menu(self):
        print("Notebook Menu:")
        print("1. Add note")
        print("2. See all notes")
        print("3. Modify note")
        print("4. xxxxxx ")
        print("5. Quit")
    
    def add_note(self):
        memo = input("enter memo for note:")
        tags = input("Enter tags separated by commas:")
        self.notebook.add_note(memo, tags)
        print("Note added ")

    def show_notes(self):
        self.notebook.scroll()

    def modify_note(self):

            id = int(input('Input note Id to be modified or enter 0 to quit: '))
            if id > 0:
                memo = input('Type in new memo or Press enter ')
                tags = input('Type in tags separated by comma or Press enter ')
                if memo > "" or tags >"":
                    print(tags)
                    self.notebook.modify_note(id,memo,tags)

    def quit(self):
        print("Thanks for using the notebook app!")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

Comment: Avoid using a [mutable default arg](https://betterprogramming.pub/mutable-default-arguments-in-python-643ae2583e00).

Comment: When you called `self.notebook.add_note(memo, tags)`, `tags` was a string (from `input()`.  Perhaps you meant to call `.split(',')` on that string?

Comment: JH. Thank you. Removing the default from the init somehow solved the problem, but somehow what was happening in my code does not seem to exactly jive with what the article in your link said. Can you please elaborate on this a little more to explain why a default list is being seen as a string?

Comment: jasonharper: Thanks. split(',') method solved the issue!